# Why a provider combination will not notify its new state in a dart test?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am new to riverpod and I am following the documentation on the providers combination.

I get a behaviour that I don't understand when combining providers and testing the output in a dart test (outside test_widgets).
I tried to outlined it in a simple code as below :

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:riverpod/riverpod.dart';

final positiveProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

final negativeProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 0);

final combinedProvider = Provider<int>((ref) {
  final positive = ref.watch(positiveProvider);
  final negative = ref.watch(negativeProvider);

  print('Counter state: ${positive - negative}');
  return positive - negative;
});

class CounterListener extends Mock {
  void call(int? previous, int value);
}

void main() {
  test('Test riverpod provider combination', () {
    final container = ProviderContainer();
    addTearDown(container.dispose);

    final counterListener = CounterListener();

    container.listen(combinedProvider, counterListener, fireImmediately: true);

    verify(counterListener.call(null, 0)).called(1);

    container.read(positiveProvider.state).state = 1;

    verify(counterListener.call(0, 1)).called(1);
  });
}
```

I am getting this results :

```
Counter state: 0 No matching calls. All calls: [VERIFIED] CounterListener.call(null, 0) (If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.) package:test_api              fail
_VerifyCall._checkWith
_makeVerify.<fn> main.<fn>

✖ Test riverpod provider combination Exited (1)
```

The behaviour is that the combined provider does not automatically fire its  inner function, which I thought it would do.

I am not sure if I misunderstood the coding pattern required for combining providers, or if it comes from the container logic in a test that is not "watched" but "listened to".

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

The provider code was right but the test's one wasn't.

The container tear down and the second verification after method called happened before the all code finished executing.

Puting the tear down at the end and a simple Future.delayed after method called resolves the issue.